# My neural network will run okay, but occasionally (every 1000) it provides an error.

Tags: r, classification, neural-networks, forecasting, error

I am using a neural network to forecast the direction of gold prices. I have created a neural network neuralnet within R. My programme runs well and i can get a prediction accuracy of about 51%. However, occasionally i get this error for my confusion matrix:

Warning message:
In confusionMatrix.default(as.factor(predicted), as.factor(actual)) :
  Levels are not in the same order for reference and data. Refactoring data to match

I realize that this is due to the fact that my network has predicted all values to be 1 (with no 0).

Why does my network make this mistake every so often?

It happens quite often for h=1 and not so much for the other architectures.

Comment: You haven’t provided any details about your implementation. How is anyone supposed to figure out the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My neural network will run okay, but occasionally (every 1000) it provides an error.

It's not an "error", per se, it's a warning. It says that it fixes the problem for you.

For one in a thousand times it's worthwhile just to leave it.

If it did that frequently the "error" would be that you could to have structured the data to avoid the message, permitting faster execution - or you could check for such conditions and apply the fix-up prior to calling the **confusionMatrix** function, then you wouldn't get the warning.

It results from the function:

```
confusionMatrix.default <- function(data, reference,
                                    positive = NULL,
                                    dnn = c("Prediction", "Reference"),
                                    prevalence = NULL,
                                    mode = "sens_spec",
                                    ...) {

    ...

  if(any(levels(reference) != levels(data))) {
    warning("Levels are not in the same order for reference and data. Refactoring data to match.")
    data <- as.character(data)
    data <- factor(data, levels = levels(reference))
  }

    ...
```

See the [documentation for confusionMatrix](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-80/topics/confusionMatrix), parameter **positive**:

```
positive

    an optional character string for the factor level that corresponds   
    to a "positive" result (if that makes sense for your data). If  
    there are only two factor levels, the first level will be used as  
    the "positive" result. When mode = "prec_recall", positive is the  
    same value used for relevant for functions precision, recall, and  
    F_meas.table.
```

> "The functions requires that the factors have exactly the same levels.
>
> For two class problems, the sensitivity, specificity, positive predictive value and negative predictive value is calculated using the positive argument. Also, the prevalence of the "event" is computed from the data (unless passed in as an argument), the detection rate (the rate of true events also predicted to be events) and the detection prevalence (the prevalence of predicted events).".

See: [StackOverflow - confusionMatrix for a classifier in R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32078108/3648282).

It's not uncommon to see the warning, in this [Ensemble Learning](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/285003_600f0736fe0a49b0b89e12426bbe87ae.html) it occurs over 1000 times.